# Adding specific Dictionary key to a list (Python 2.6)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-2.6

Hi there I've been struggling with this problem for a while now.

I have a dictionary like:

```
dict1  =  {
    'Name': 'ID Numbers', 
    'children': []
    }
```

I have an other list of dictionaries with a number of IDs in it such as:

```
list1 = [
  {
    "id": 1004,
    "othervalue": "blah blah"

  },
  {
    "id": 1008,
    "othervalue": "blah blah"

  }
```

I need to add those dictionaries to the 'children' list.

If it was 2.7 i could probably do:

```
for x in dict1:
  x['children'].append(IDs from list1)
```

Possibly? But alas it's 2.6 and I have absolutely no idea how to go about this. Any ideas would be so very much appreciated.

Expected output:

```
dict1  =  {
    'Name': 'ID Numbers', 
    'children': [

    {
    "id": 1004,
    },

    {
    "id": 1008,
    }

]
}
```

Comment: `for x in mydict3: x['children'].extend(list2)` ? It'll literally _add those dictionaries to the 'children' list_.

Comment: First off -apologies - I updated the code, I have a number of all other keys in list2 so I need to iterate over them. And that code ddin't seem to work anyways? `TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: It's still unclear what's your expected output is. Your `list1` is dict. `list2` is list of dictionaries. `mydict3` isn't even declared. Can you show us [MCVE]?

Comment: I don't understand the thing about `append`. Was `append`'s behavior modified in Python 2.7?

Comment: Sorry, I had to change the data when copying it over and made some mistakes. I have provided an expected output as well. Basically, I just want to be able to take the IDs from `list1` and put them inside the children list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although dict comprehensions are not available in Python 2.6, you still may use [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) constructor. Since it looks like you want to add multiple items to list, `extend` may be better suitable than `append`.

```
dict1['children'].extend(dict([('id', d['id'])]) for d in list1)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. Apologies for the bad explanation at the start!